# Plotting daily time series in R

Tags: r, datetime, line-plot

I'm new to R. I have daily time series data on sap flux and want to plot line graph in R and want to format x-axis for date .my data file is like this;

```
Date    G1T0    G1T1    G1T2    G1T3
19-Jul-14   0.271081377 0.342416929 0.216215197 0.414495265
20-Jul-14   0.849117059 0.778333568 0.555856888 0.375737302
21-Jul-14   0.742855108 0.756373483 0.536025029 0.255169809
22-Jul-14   0.728504928 0.627172734 0.506561041 0.244863511
23-Jul-14   0.730702865 0.558290192 0.452253842 0.223213402
24-Jul-14   0.62732916  0.461480279 0.377567279 0.180328992
25-Jul-14   0.751401513 0.5404663   0.517567416 0.204342317
```

Please help me by sample R script.

Comment: This question is poorly formulated. Please read the posting guide and how to make a good [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# install.packages("ggplot2")
# install.packages("scales")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d-%b-%y")
ggplot(data = data, x = Date) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = G1T0, col = "G1T0")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = G1T1, col = "G1T1")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = G1T2, col = "G1T2")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = G1T3, col = "G1T3")) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Group") +
  labs(y = "Measurement", x = "Date")
```

What this does is loads a couple of packages to do the plot (obviously, if you don't have those packages, install them), then it formats  your date so R knows they're dates (the format argument I used matched your particular string pattern), then it calls the ggplot function to map your data.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Actually I did it by this code;library(zoo)
g1 <-read.table("group1-goto.csv",header=T,sep=",")
head(g1)
summary(g1)
g1$Date <- as.Date(g1$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=g1, aes(Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = G1T0, colour = "black",linetype="dotte",size="5")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = G1T1, colour = "blue"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = G1T2, colour = "red"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = G1T3, colour = "green"))+
  xlab("Date")+
  ylab("Sap Flux")+
  ggtitle("Group-1_Daily Normalized Sap Flux")+theme(plot.title=element_text(size=20,color="blue"))  now I want to format  the plot,Tnx.